# Azure Service Fabric Application stuck in Deleting state

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I had a deployment on my service fabric cluster go wrong; I attempted to delete an application and for some reason, the deletion never seemed to  and now the application is stuck in the deleting state, while all my deployments remain.  I can't delete or upgrade the application since I get a status of "deleting"

Is there a way to update the status of the application so I can then proceed to delete it (for real) this time?

Answer (score 3):

You'll most likely need to use power shell and execute an application delete that way, I had this issue as well when starting out with service fabric.

For instructions on how to connect to the cluster using powershell click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster).

```
$nodes = Get-ServiceFabricNode

foreach ($node in $nodes)
{
    $replicas = Get-ServiceFabricDeployedReplica -NodeName $node.NodeName -ApplicationName "fabric:/AppNameHere"

    foreach ($replica in $replicas)
    {
        Remove-ServiceFabricReplica -ForceRemove -NodeName $node.NodeName -PartitionId $replica.PartitionId -ReplicaOrInstanceId $replica.ReplicaOrInstanceId
    }
}
```

Deletions that get stuck, in my experience, are often due to the application not honoring cancellation tokens.  What kind of application did you deploy?